# Find old branches with no PRs

Tags: git, github, pull-request

For a given repository on GitHub, how can I list all branches that were never the source (compare branch) of a pull request?

If possible I'd like to filter the results by branch creation date (specifying a cutoff).

The goal is to find old, unmerged published branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://github.com/owner/repo/branches/stale` (e.g. https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/branches/stale) lists old branches along with their PR status (Closed, Merged, or awaiting PR).